# Parse Contact detail by URI

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.1, android-contacts

I was wondering is there is a way of parsing a contact details (number,email etc.) by a specific uri address which received by the contact list

example:
//assume that the data variable ia already populated with a uri address of a specific contact which was picked up from the contact list

Uri contact =   contact = data.getData();

how could I acutely parse the contact details by it's number, email, organisation and so on..?

thanks,

ray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Email you can use

```
// query for everything email
            cursor = getContentResolver().query(Email.CONTENT_URI, null,
                    Email.CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[] { id }, null);

            int emailIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Email.DATA);

            // let's just get the first email
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
             String email = cursor.getString(emailIdx);
            }
```

Change Email with Phone you'll get contact no.

Comment: Yes, but how would you provide the URI in this query?